# How does producer process data in a queue in AWS SQS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I've a doubt, let's assume in consumer I've set the receive messages limit to 10 for queue, delay of 5 seconds and polling rate as 20 sec.
I want to know how my consumer  processes the data, whether it process the total 10 data at once and then picks up another 10 or it process one data and simultaneously picks one from the queue?

Comment: That depends **entirely** on the way you code your consumer.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how my consumer processes the data, whether it process the total 10 data at once and then picks up another 10 or it process one data and simultaneously picks one from the queue?

If you're asking about how batches get processed, the former is correct. If your consumer is a lambda function for example, the function would recieve a single "batch" of 10 messages per invocation. It would then have to process or fail to process all 10 before starting another batch.

If you are in fact using lambda, I'd suggest reading [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) for more basic information.